# field name is getting changed in response data

Tags: jmeter

Field name is getting changed after executing the script.

A. After executing the script,the field name is not getting displayed in response data but the parameters are displayed with slight changes.

In sampler below details are getting displayed.

```
Name : aura.token
Parameters : HCQAHBgEMTAwMBQCGAcxMDAwMjA5GAcxMDAwMjA5ABQCGfMQscHV8XF654tDbfY0XD3yRxaSwbvRh1oAGfMgzIG_YaBrAZdWB-IAMP_0iAQiYMHheBA3BA0SoXzWh4kA
```

but after execution of a script below details are getting displayed in response data.

```
*/{"event":{"descriptor":"markup://aura:invalidSession","attributes":{"values":{"newToken":"HCQAHBgEMTAwMBQCGAcxMDAwMjA5GAcxMDAwMjA5ABQCGfMQkaKR6n5r5QqE7gz5Qk1l1Rb67KOtiFoAGfMgtKaMHHWJZiXEOt8pU6zs1edK_Q4dQo5VL2ea8y2qi3gA"}}},"exceptionEvent":true}/*ERROR*/
```

Comment: Which field value is getting changed ?

Answer (score 0):

It's name is "newToken". So why do you think this should not be changed?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you need to perform [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter) of this field, to wit you will not be able just to record and replay the script as this "token" is being generated dynamically and has new value each time you access the application.

The main idea of the correlation is

1. Identifying dynamic elements. The easiest way is to record your test scenario one more time using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) and compare the recorded scripts. All parameters which are different needs to be handled properly.
2. Wherever you detect a dynamic parameter look into previous sampler response data (body, [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers), [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies), URL) - the value should be there
3. Apply a relevant [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to the previous sampler in order to extract the dynamic value and store it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
4. Replace recorded value with the JMeter Variable from the previous step
5. You should be good to go now.